# Is the wall created by a "Wall Of…" spell considered to be an object?

Tags: dnd-4e, spells

Is the wall created by a *Wall Of X* spell, e.g. *Wall of Ice*, considered to be an object, and hence immune to the stuff objects are immune to?

According to the Rules Compendium p177, they're immune to:

> necrotic damage, poison damage, psychic damage and any attack that targets Will

Comment: Since most walls have defenses detailed that include will... I would say... maybe? I'm amused that you could poison a wall of ice though.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Walls have the *Conjuration* keyword, so normally they can't be attacked at all. Some walls (such as *Wall of Ice*) explicitly state they can be attacked, however, which brings us to your situation.

There doesn't seem to be any official rules covering this, but it seems like when you conjure something it's a creature (in which case it usually has the *Summoning* keyword and has its own rules regarding being attacked), some kind of energy effect (such as *Wall of Fire*, which can't be attacked at all), or an animated physical object (such as *Wall of Ice*). The fact that you've animated the object doesn't really make it stop being an object: if you had caused a sword to fly around and hit people, it would still be a sword and thus immune to poison, mind control, etc. It seems like your *creation* of an object (such as ice) also wouldn't affect its being an object.

In summary, if it would count as an object if you *weren't* responsible for creating it, why would the detail of it being created by you rather than naturally occurring make it *not* count as an object?

On a side note, conjurations use your defenses when attacked, so that huge chunk of ice uses your Reflex defense to "dodge" attacks.